# How to convert lowercase to uppercase in OpenCL or vise-versa

Tags: c++, buffer, opencl, kronos-workforce-central

Hi i have a vector of char16 containing some special characters and lowercase alphabets, is is possible to check each char if :

1.) is an alphabet? if it is then i would convert it to lowercase letter or vice versa

2.) if its a special characters or spaces (eg. ' ' or ' " ' aka apos or ',' or '-' etc. then i would leave it as it is

Below is my unfinished kernel, i  before moving my character by 'n' amount, i would like to check each character if its a char and convert it to upper/lower case

```
__kernel void A2_T2_B(      
                        __global int n,
                        __global char16* char_vec,
                        __global char* encrypted,
                        __global char* decrypted        ) {



int i = get_global_id(0);



if (n>0)
{
     if(any(char_vec[i]=='z')==1))
     {

     }
     char_vec[i]+=n;

}

else if(n<0)
{
     char_vec[i]-=n;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL doesn't have any built-in string handling functions if that's what you're asking. You will need to implement them yourself, or find a 3rd party library.

There isn't a general answer we can give, because the implementation will depend heavily on the encoding. For plain ASCII, you can use something like:

```
bool isupper(char c)
{
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
```

Comment: this codes above is to be implemented in the kernel itself or inside .cpp file?

Comment: This should work in the kernel as far as I'm aware.

Comment: can u elaborate what does this method do? because befire tghis u were using the if-else instead...  sorry as im super new to opencl

Answer (score 1):

Just add this simple condition for conversion

```
for (int i = 0; arr[i] != '\n'; i++) {
    if (arr[i] <= 'a' && arr[i] >= 'z') {
        arr[i] = (int)arr[i] - 32;     // A: 65, a: 97 ;  a - A = 32
        // or   arr[i] = arr[i] - ' ';
   }
}
```

Comment: @JamesOmnipotent `"A"` is not guaranteed to be 97 nor are letters guaranteed to be sequential or ordered in any sane fashion, so watch out.